# Implement Oberver Pattern using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-2, observer-pattern

I need to implement [**Observer Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in ASP.NET MVC. Can anyone guide me where I can find the skeleton of the classes for this or can provide me a skeleton itself?

I need to apply this pattern with the clear separation of model, view and controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this example: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/490/observer-pattern/

Comment: Yes I have. And I already have the framework classes. But I am not sure how to implement it in ASP.NET MVC. I believe some these classes need to be converted into controller.